# How to make field available only when optional param was passed?

Tags: typescript

In the following example, is it possible to make `parse()` available only if `key` was passed using TypeScript?

```
// SOURCE CODE:
interface Input {
    key?: string;
    data: Record<string, string>;
}

interface Options {
    parse: (x: string) => void;
}

type HelperFunc = (options: Options) => void;

const myFunc = (input: Input, helper: HelperFunc): void => {

    // How to implement this such that if key is passed, only then make `parse()` available?
    // CONSTRAINT: I don't want to make `parse()` an optional field because user will call
    // it multiple times and I don't want them to do `parse?.()` all the time.

    if (input.key) {
        helper({ parse: (x) => `${x} parsed using ${input.key}` })
    } else {
        helper({});  // currently throws valid TypeScript error
    }

    // do something with input.data
};

// EXPECTED USAGE:
myFunc({
    key: "my-key",
    data: {
       "someData": "someValue"
    }
}, ({ parse }) => {
    // No TypeScript errors
    parse("parse this");
    parse("parse that");
    parse("parse this and that");
});

// mentioning parse should throw TypeScript error because key was not passed
myFunc({
    data: {
       "someData": "someValue"
    }
}, ({ parse }) => {
    /* either throw error here when calling or while de-structuring above */ 
    parse("parse this");
});
```

I'm just wondering if this is possible using TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) the `myFunc` function.

First declare two types of interfaces that will be used for each of your parameters. First - ones that have no key:

```
interface InputData {
    data: Record<string, string>;
}

type EmptyHelperFunc = (options: {}) => void;
```

And ones where all data is present:

```
type Input = {
    key?: string;
} & InputData;

interface Options {
    parse: (x: string) => void;
}

type HelperFunc = (options: Options) => void;
```

The overload type can then be declared and used as follows:

```
type MyFuncOverload = {
    (input: InputData, helper: EmptyHelperFunc): void
    (input: Required<Input>, helper: HelperFunc): void
}

const myFunc: MyFuncOverload = (input: Input, helper: HelperFunc): void => {
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUHkFUCUGECip6QCKIFwCgCWA7AFwFMAnAMwEMBjY0ASXwAcBXQtSwy0Ab21AGgAJp0qZQsYtQD2pIQB4AzoVIEA5gBpQy1fjUA%20ANzYAvtmyEAnkzqNWhUAF5e-QQGtilgPzid64yagAGQMzGwcXMZ4RGRUtKCQTIS40viKLoKgTJSkisTiABQAHr4q6gCUTvqgAG7SuEIB5lY2oAASxAA2NqQAYiz41E6gBdJJKWniicmpipWO1XUNUS10iAC2SZYd3WT9g8Oj47PiPCbzi-WNzdZ0ALKW%209SQNWSd0pRCw3yZBQT24js4VEWgAFl0euINlsdj0nuVxEshK4BH8woRAeiwRCyOJYXsBtQEbUrqZzDI0g51o9CeIHk8Xm8Pl9nGiAaF7NjdqQ8Ti%20oTiUiqi4UaAQO1pAB3UCEaSgXCbTrEdbEIgy0G4dKKFjUUHqzjy8igDyWeXpbKKPJCLSpTqmwjg-CgdaUDygAAG2VyxAK5XdoEoNUouE6lAARkqvKLxagAHLgAAqsAAgvRYwnAcJUgByBySyhq2XO110T05PK%20-0F0BjGb4SidUDkXBdL5hqSUFh5UBdsigSUhxvUBudaNgXBUlidZJMJUyhXEdIFr70LP4XP9gsOB3KmVyoRysverwAOkrAc6jZ385VJ-MmVwRrZbBPJsqP0ygnB3IKPCy5fyEYiguD0ABIeCKQIvStHtFHUUBwP%20F8TRMf1zlFQIum7D9P1Ab8el-c5DAEcVqBYUhSFVQg7XVUgpXSINOgaUAE1ucBqFUJJQDIOjSAw%209BHFA9tGkFUHXggcHXldETxELhTCicVEAADQABUQeAE0QNBQGgcBkwAcSwbBqSeX9RRNcQACJqQAWhNKyNFFOSxAyXCrMUUTiAiSgrOszyVQANQbFhiCs-iTC0X9-29UBzmFHCxTAWM5VYmx2M4hweNkRRRWgn0rPy9VNSs8pjEyfKCkKgD9UIUrysESrqti8Sl3wL4HU4erTDK8xxRVIgJngorFFBaQpw60E6OlNLiAy3AuOy0hQHbYde2NTxN3SfBpAcC0rRMmlBnMzIXNOUVBA8ryfL80ArqCkKwoiqK-yK%20KFjckiACpuIncFlodabuIo2Q8LIOhJUdUBh0veDQchkM6CEYhbJ0HVCHI%20Dw2kV5QC%20sA8oAqqita7qiKAA).